# How to save the results of a loop in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, loops

To analyze the prices of different products I have created a function that downloads them through the selenium library, however, when I execute the routine step by step it works fine, but when I try to encapsulate it in a function it saves only the last value.

this is my code

```
import random # Para generar números aleatorios
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import sleep # Para detener la ejecución de los programas durante un tiempo definido
from selenium import webdriver # Para ejecutar acciones a través de un navegador web
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service #Para que webdriver seleccione automáticamente el driver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager # Para llamar el driver que permite controlar Google Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from types import ModuleType, FunctionType # Para la función que remueve los elementos del environment



def scraping_jumbo(url):
  
  #Descarga la versión más actualizada del driver de Chrome
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
  
  #Abre el navegador según la url especificada
  driver.get(url)
  
  #Detiene el algoritmo mientras carga la página entre 10 y 15 segundos
  sleep(random.uniform(10.0, 15.0))
  
  #Recorre el código html de la página para encontrar "shelf-item"
  items = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"shelf-item")
  
  #Crea diferentes arreglos vacíos a rellenar en el ciclo for
  data = []
  
  for item in items: 
    titulo=item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "shelf-product-title-text").text
    print(titulo)
    marca=item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "shelf-product-brand").text
    try:
      precio=item.find_element("xpath", './/span[@class="price-best"] | .//span[@class="product-sigle-price-wrapper"]').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
      np.nan

    data.append({'titulo': titulo,
      'marca': marca, 
      'precio': precio})
    print(data)
    
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    return df
  

data_jumbo = scraping_jumbo("https://www.jumbo.cl/mascotas?page=1")
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the indent of the `pd.DataFrame` line. Move it outside of the for loop.